# Opentelemetry Java auto-instrumentation data to Jaeger

Tags: java, spring, jaeger, open-telemetry

I'm new to the world of Opentelemetry and would like to send the [Spring-petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic) instrumentation data to Jaeger which is running on my remote cloud system

Here is the bat file:
`java -javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar -Dotel.exporter=jaeger -Dotel.exporter.jaeger.endpoint=50.18.XXX.XX:14250 -Dotel.otlp.span.timeout=4000 -Dotel.jaeger.service.name=otel-ui -jar target/spring-petclinic-2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar`

When I run the bat file, I'm abe to open the petclinic app in browser (http://localhost:8080), I get the following error in the console:
`[opentelemetry.auto.trace 2021-01-06 17:22:21:008 +0530] [grpc-default-executor-1] WARN io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.OtlpGrpcSpanExporter - Failed to export spans. Error message: UNAVAILABLE: io exception`

How to resolve this issue? Are there any other dependencies to be the added to the petclinic pom.xml or to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC port isn't enabled in your jaeger instance.

You can try a docker-compose file like this

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one
    ports:
      - 5775:5775/udp
      - 6831:6831/udp
      - 6832:6832/udp
      - 5778:5778
      - 16686:16686
      - 14268:14268
      - 14250:14250
      - 9411:9411
```

And you can connect to it without problems

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the Collector config file? It seems you are using the gRPC protocol and it's not supported on the system where the collector is running.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/master/exporter/otlpexporter/README.md